# How can I change a MahApps.Metro progress bar color, based on the current theme?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have a MahApps.Metro progress bar defined like this;

```
<Controls:MetroProgressBar Name="progressBar"
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     Grid.Row="2"
                     Minimum="0"
                     Maximum="100"
                     Height="20"
                     Foreground="LightBlue"
                                   />
```

Instead of having the `Foreground` defined as a static  LightBlue, I'd like to have it change based on my current theme.

I'm changing the themes using their ThemeManager

```
MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(System.Windows.Application.Current,
                                    MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.GetAccent(myAccent),
                                    MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.GetAppTheme(myTheme));
```

Is there a way to get whatever the current Theme or Accent is from the application and into the xaml file?

Comment: have you tried using Foreground="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"?

Comment: That works perfectly.  Thank you.  If you put this as the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current themes' accent color is defined in resource `AccentColor` as a Color and in resource `AccentColorBrush` as a Brush. You can simply assign the Brush to your progressbar:

```
<Controls:MetroProgressBar Name="progressBar"
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     Grid.Row="2"
                     Minimum="0"
                     Maximum="100"
                     Height="20"
                     Foreground="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
                                   />
```

Answer (score 1):

Bonus answer: Here is how you change it with a binding to a `bool` in the `DataContext`. It reverts back to the default when the bound property is false

```xml
<Controls:MetroProgressBar.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Controls:MetroProgressBar">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PublicBoolInDataContext}"
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkRed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Controls:MetroProgressBar.Style>
```